# Why would typeof(Foo) ever return null?

Tags: c#, .net

Occasionally, I see that `typeof(Foo)` returns null.  Why would this happen?

This is in C#, .NET 3.5.

I thought it might have something to do with the assembly containing the type not yet being loaded, but a test app shows that the assembly is loaded at the start of the method where `typeof` is used.

Any ideas?

---

**Update 1**

- I can't provide a reproducible sample as this happens on a huge application
- When I say 'occasionally' I mean in the same method in my application but during various instances.  Also, when it fails once when running, it'll fail every time for that instance of the application.

---

**Update 2**

The application in question uses a huuuuuge amount of memory and runs on 32bit XP.  I'm thinking maybe it's a TypeLoadException or OutOfMemoryException that's somehow being swallowed (but I can't see how, as I've tried this with first-chance exceptions turned on in the debugger).

---

**Update 3**

Ran into the same issue just now.  Here's the stack trace:
[image]
The code up to this point is literally just:

```
Type tradeType = typeof(MyTradeType)
TradeFactory.CreateTrade(tradeType)
```

*(before, it was `..CreateTrade(typeof(MyTradeType))` so **I couldn't actually tell if the `typeof` returned null**)*

So, it looks like **`typeof()` isn't returning null** but it's **getting set to null by the time it ends up in the `CreateTrade` method**.

The exception (`NullReferenceException`) has a `HResult` property of `0x80004003` (`Invalid pointer`).  A call to `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error( )` (in the Immediate Window) returns `127 (The specified procedure could not be found)`.
I've looked in the Modules window and the module that contains this type and method has been loaded and there doesn't look to be any loader errors.

---

Comment: Interesting.  Can you provide a code sample that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Does "Occasionally" mean sporadically on the same call or in certain places but not others?

Comment: I for one cannot imagine any way this can ever happen.

Comment: Please show the entire statement where this is happening. I suspect you are leaving out some important information.

Comment: Maybe something else is broken? Or you are doing something wrong?

Comment: This is possibly a question for Eric Lippert and company.

Answer (score 4):

Has loading the dll failed for some reason? Have you checked the [fusion logs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx).

I'd assume this would cause more problems than just this, but if you're doing this check before using anything from the assembly, it may be hiding any further problems.

Answer (score 2):

Since `typeof(T)`  is a compile time operator the loading-time of the assembly won't be involved.

It would be interesting to see some code that demonstrates this.

Even more interesting to see it happen sometimes and sometimes not.

A first answer might be : use `GetType()` on an instance.

Comment: Resolution is compile time, but the loader loads the module containing IFoo at the start of the method.

Answer (score 1):

typeof determines the type during the compile time. So even if it returns null then it should return null always. Because the behavior does not change during the runtime. Give some code snippet some other stuff is broken.

Comment: But I can't see how it can return null.  I'm trying to reproduce a test app that uses lots of memory as I think it's a type load exception that's being swallowed.

Comment: @Steve I didn't mean that typeof will return null. But since the type is deduced during compile time the behavior should remain the same during the runtime. It cannot behave differently at different times. As far as I know typeof has never returned null.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem in my VSPackage project when using typeof(MyClass) in the package's constructor.  I moved my code to the overridden Initialize() method and then it worked fine, so it looks like the assembly not being loaded yet may be a factor in this error some times. I'll note too that my VSPackage is loaded at run-time into Visual Studio via MEF, so this likely isn't your typically scenario, but still thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible and very easy to reproduce.
`typeof(T)` will return null if the type has been created in memory.
Through `System.Reflection.Emit` for example.

Comment: Makes some sense. But any ideas on why it would return null for a compiled class would be helpful, too.