# Type of class is null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, typeof

I created a class X that extends from ICommand

```
public class X: ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
       //DO SOMETHING.
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get this class as command in the ViewModel.

```
public ICommand XCommand{ get; set; }
```

in my ctor:

```
 XCommand= CommandRepository.Instance.GetCommand(typeof(X));
```

I can to do `typeof` to class X because it null, why?

Comment: typeof(X) returns null?

Comment: @yBee yes, I add pic from my debugging, take a look

Comment: This is not possible. Please try following: `var type = typeof(MyTypename)`;'

Comment: In the screenshot you are just hovering over the class name. Did you deduce from that that typeof(X) is null OR you got a compiler/runtime error?

Comment: I do not uderstand why the class is null (like the img)

Comment: why is "`AxisOpenErrorCommand`" blocked-out?

Comment: @publicgk the class name not supposed to be NULL! and i saw the null in the line XCommand= CommandRepository.Instance.GetCommand(typeof(X)); also.

Comment: In your debugger set a breakpoint in your code somewhere and enter "? AxisOpenErrorCommand" into the Immediate Window, this will give you a complete plaintext printout of the state of the class and any static members - or an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly see similar topics:

- [Why would typeof(Foo) ever return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745853/why-would-typeoffoo-ever-return-null)
- [typeof(T) may return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497570/typeoft-may-return-null)

Particurarly look at the [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497570/typeoft-may-return-null/6498637#6498637) in the second link.